# GDB on any executable?

Tags: debugging

Is it possible to use the GNU debugger on executables that were not compiled with GNU tools(gcc, gas, g++) and dump the assembly code?

Comment: Doesn't seem related to infosec.

Comment: @NeilSmithline i intend to dissect malware.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use gdb on any executable. Without debugging symbols, some of the commands won't work, but there's plenty of commands that work at the assembly level. `stepi` to single-step instructions, you can `print` registers (using C-like expression syntax: `print $rbx+($rax<<$rcx)`) and modify them.

But for generating an assembly dump of the whole program, `objdump -d` is easier. `objdump -D` if there's code in weird places (which is sometimes the case with malware). And `objdump -s` for a view of the data segment.